# Custom BroadcastReceiver is calling twice android parse.com

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, parse-platform, android-broadcast

I have created Custom BroadCast Receiver below is the code

```
public class MyCustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String TAG = "MyCustomReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    try {
        if (intent.getAction() != null
                && intent.getAction().equals(
                        "com.example.parsepushexample.UPDATE_STATUS")) {
            System.out.println("call MyReceiver onRecive method");
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, MyCallService.class);
            context.startService(intent2);
            System.out.println("service started over");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

and in menifest file

```
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  <receiver
        android:name="com.example.parsepushexample.MyCustomReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.parsepushexample.UPDATE_STATUS" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="MyCallService"></service>
```

Also i am getting notification but my problem is that every time the **onReceive** is called twice :(

Comment: How it's possible my friend???

Comment: so you call sendBroadcast twice?

Comment: no my friend every single send broadcast i am getting twice onReceive

Comment: change the action and try again and see what happens

Comment: I have same problem like you but actually i dont have that problem but my problem is in sending mail,i solved that, may be this link usefull for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23623403/android-service-start-when-push-notification-send-and-stop-after-service-task-co

Answer (score 0):

That means you are getting two broadcasts with same intent

```
com.example.parsepushexample.UPDATE_STATUS
```

Check your logic for sending broadcast, There must be some issue.

**Check below soultion from [This Link](https://www.parse.com/questions/receiving-notifications-twice)**

Removing the alert tag in payload, solved

Thanks to this thread

https://www.parse.com/questions/how-suppress-push-notification-from-being-displayed

Comment: ya :( i have checkd i am sending pushnotification from parse.com and i can't see in that

Comment: how to remove alert payload

Comment: and what used instead alert