# Android Service start when push notification send and stop after service task complete

Tags: android, service, push-notification, parse-platform

i want to start service when i send push notification through parse.com and when task of service ( backgrounds work) complete i stop the service. 
EDIT : in my service for sending mail

```
 try {
                sender = new GMailSender("id",
                        "password");

                sender.sendMail(
                        "subject",
                        "This is Body", "sender mail id",
                        "recei. id");


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);
            }
```

Gmail sender class

```
  public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator{
  //public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {   
private String mailhost ="smtp.gmail.com";   
private String user;   
private String password;   
private Session session;  
private Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
MimeMessage message;

static {   
    Security.addProvider(new com.provider.JSSEProvider());   
}  

public GMailSender(String user, String password) {   
    this.user = user;   
    this.password = password;   

    Properties props = new Properties();   
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);   
}   

protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {   
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);   
}   

public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {   
    try{
    message = new MimeMessage(session);   
    DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
    message.setSubject(subject);   
    message.setDataHandler(handler); 


    if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
    else  
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
    Transport.send(message);   
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    Transport.send(message);
}   

    public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
        message.setContent(multipart);
        System.out.println("u r in add attachment"+multipart);
      }
```

//  } 
//
    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
        private byte[] data;
        private String type;

```
    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {   
        super();   
        this.data = data;   
        this.type = type;   
    }   

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {   
        super();   
        this.data = data;   
    }   

    public void setType(String type) {   
        this.type = type;   
    }   

    public String getContentType() {   
        if (type == null)   
            return "application/octet-stream";   
        else  
            return type;   
    }   

    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {   
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);   
    }   

    public String getName() {   
        return "ByteArrayDataSource";   
    }   

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {   
        throw new IOException("Not Supported");   
    }   
}
```

}

Jsse class

```
    public class JSSEProvider extends Provider {
public JSSEProvider() {
    super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
    AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
        public Void run() {
            put("SSLContext.TLS",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
            put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
            put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
            put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: what your service is doing?

Comment: i add my question in following link that contain my entire code : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602926/android-service-called-twice-and-twice-repeatedly-and-automatic-after-first-time

Comment: use IntentService rather Service. IntentService will create seprate thread and execute given task and stop  itself as task complete

Comment: if you give any example of IntentService and my which method i called where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes sure you can see the example

```
    public class MyService extends IntentService {

    public MyService(String name) {
        super("");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
        sendEmail();
    }

    public void sendEmail() {
        try {
            String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            String address = "biraj@gmail.com";
            String from = "biraj@gmial.com";
            String pass = "biraj123";
            String to = "akash@gmail.com";

            Multipart multiPart;
            String finalString = "";

            Properties props = System.getProperties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
            props.put("mail.smtp.user", address);
            props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
            Log.i("Check", "done pops");
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            Store store = session.getStore();
            store.connect(host, address, pass);

            DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(finalString.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            message.setDataHandler(handler);
            Log.i("Check", "done sessions");
            multiPart = new MimeMultipart();
            InternetAddress toAddress;
            toAddress = new InternetAddress(to);
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
            Log.i("Check", "added recipient");
            message.setSubject("Send Auto-Mail");
            message.setContent(multiPart);
            message.setText("Demo For Sending Mail in Android Automatically");
            Log.i("check", "transport");
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            Log.i("check", "connecting");
            transport.connect(host, address, pass);
            Log.i("check", "wana send");
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
            Log.i("check", "sent");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:**

No need to make separate thread or asynctask. Put the code directly that you want to execute  in  `onHandleIntent()` method.

Service will stop itself as task gets completed.

Comment: after doing above change ,actually i found that my sending mail have some problem, i separate the code of sending mail and know that mail have their have problem in sending, i edit my question with sending mail code above and please help to find problem of sending mail twice at a time.

Comment: Weldon,friends it working for me,thank you very much plus mark :)